# Apache Camel http component timer dockerization

Tags: apache, docker, spring-boot, apache-camel

What I am trying to achieve is to dockerise a spring boot app which uses camel to periodically check an external rest end point and insert the data received to a database.I currently use timer to trigger the route.

But I need to dockerise it which will create problems like triggering the route from all containers.

I know about scheduler which can use a cron expression.But again it will be triggered from all containers.

Looking for some design insights from experts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean from all containers? And are you using any container platform like Kubernetes? If so it has a CronJob deployment which you can take a look at. Mind that a job is intended to execute and terminate, but you can use it to run the job scheduled periodically via cron syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any Database as part of you application the task will be simple. Create a table and put and an entry in the column `status` as  `running` and `completed`. By `scheduler` before hitting the external api check for the `status` in the DB. If it's `running` abort the call or if the status is `completed` run the job and call the external service. You can also use some `in-memory` cache like `memcache` or `redis` as an alternative to Database.

Best approach is trigger the loadbalancer of your all containers by some external triggers like `control-M` or `Cloudwatch` in `AWS` so that request will be directed to one container so no additional call will be made to the external api. or you have to use inter container communication which will add more complexity to your application.